# Interact with svg file saved in Google Drive with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, svg

I am developing an application in Apps Script to access information about svg images.

With two cascading drop-down menus (one for the country and one for the cities in the selected country), I display an svg and be able to interact with it.

Here is an example of a svg ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JJtjOQZ6NZeI1nUPlh-WWEosSJGdHc17/view?usp=sharing)) :
[image]

I would like a text to appear when hovering over the circle. This data is present in [this Sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QVBlloolo5Mn_wEXC6P-pk6kMn8s1MgNt55jvjiphws/edit?usp=sharing) ("DB" tab) :

[image]

Columns A and B are used to feed my drop-down menus. Column C is the url of the image that should be displayed when the city is selected. Column D is the id of the red circles in the svg and column E is the text I would like to see appear when the mouse hovers over the circle.

I managed to import the svg into my code. However, I would like to add a title tag for each circle. It only works halfway. Indeed, only one of the two titles is carried over and I don't see what's wrong.

Here is the html code of my page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
     <link href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>  
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="form-row divHtml">
       <div class="form-group col-md-10">
         <h1 class="titre">Select Country and City that you want : </h1>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-row divHtml">
       <div class="form-group col-md-5">
         <label for="country" class="libFields">Country : <span style="color: #e7343f">*</span></label>
         <select type="text" id="country" class="form-control" onchange="getCitiesJS();">
           <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
             <?!=getCountries()?>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-5">
         <label for="city" class="libFields">City : <span style="color: #e7343f">*</span></label>
         <select type="text" id="city" class="form-control" onchange="showPicture()">
         </select>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-row divHtml">
       <div id="image"></div>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the JavaScript code for my application:

```
<script>
   function getCitiesJS(){
     var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
     document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "Choose...";
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(city => {
       document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = city
     }).getCities(country);
   }

     function showPicture(){
       var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
       var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(image => {
         document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = image;
       }).getPicture(country,city);
       sleep(3000).then(() =>{
         addTitlesJS();
       });
     }

     function addTitlesJS(){
       var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cls-1");
       for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++){
         var idSVG = elements[i].id;
         console.log(idSVG)
         google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(result => {
    document.getElementById(idSVG).innerHTML = "<title>" + result + "</title>"
         }).getTitle(idSVG);
       }
     }

     function sleep (time) {
       return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
     }
 </script>
```

And here is the Apps Script code of my application :

```
 function doGet(e){
   if(!e.parameter.page){
     return render('Index').setTitle('Centers of Interest');
   }
 }

 function include(filename){
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
 }


 function render(file){
   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
   var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var admin = userRights(userEmail);
   if(admin){
     return tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
   }
 }

 function userRights(user){
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const ws = ss.getSheetByName('users');
   const plage = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow()).getValues().map(r => r[0].toString().toLowerCase());
   const posIndex = plage.indexOf(user.toString().toLowerCase());
   const rowNumber = posIndex === -1 ? 0 : posIndex + 1;
   if(rowNumber > 0){ return true; } 
   else { return false; }
 }

 function getCountries(){
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const ws = ss.getSheetByName('BDD');
   var countries = ws.getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');
   var tCountries = [];
   countries.forEach(function(x){
     if(tCountries.indexOf(x[0]) === -1){
       tCountries.push(x[0])
     }
   });
   return tCountries.map(d => '<option>' + d + '</option>').join('');
 }

 function getCities(country){
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const ws = ss.getSheetByName('BDD');
   var countriesCities = ws.getRange('A2:B').getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');
   var cities = [["Choose..."]], tCities = [], selectedCities = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < countriesCities.length; i ++){
     if (countriesCities[i][0] == country){
       cities.push([countriesCities[i][1]]);
     }
   }
   cities.push(["Undefined"]);
   cities.forEach(function(x){
     if(tCities.indexOf(x[0]) === -1){
       tCities.push(x[0])
     }
   });
   for (let i = 0; i < tCities.length; i ++){
     if(tCities[i] === "Choose..."){
       selectedCities.push('<option disabled selected>Choose...</option>');
     }
     else{
       selectedCities.push('<option>' + tCities[i] + '</option>');
     }
   }
   return selectedCities.join('');
 }

 function getPicture(country,city){
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const ws = ss.getSheetByName('BDD');
   var tPictures = ws.getRange('A2:C').getValues().filter(d =>d[0] !== '');
   var charSet = 'ISO-8859-1'
   for (let i = 0; i < tPictures.length; i ++){
     if (tPictures[i][0] === country){
       if (tPictures[i][1] === city){
         var idFile = tPictures[i][2];
         var file = DriveApp.getFileById(idFile);
         var codeHtml = file.getBlob().getDataAsString(charSet);
         return codeHtml;
       }
     }
   }
 }

 function getTitle(id){
   // Déclaration des constantes et des variables
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuilleBDD = classeur.getSheetByName("BDD");
   var tDonnees = [];

   tDonnees = feuilleBDD.getRange("D2:E").getValues().filter(d=>d[0] != "");
   for(let i = 0; i < tDonnees.length; i ++){
     if(tDonnees[i][0] === id){
       return tDonnees[i][1];
     }
   }
 }
```

For me, the problem comes from the addTitleJS function but I don't see where. If anyone can help me or knows of an alternative to answer my question, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand that script. First, you get the SVG file content as a string: `file.getBlob().getDataAsString(charSet)`, then you you set that string as the `.src` property of a `<div>`: `document.getElementById("image").src = image`. What does that achieve?

Comment: This pastes in my div which has the id "image" the content of the code of my svg. It works well, I can see my image as well as my red circles.

Comment: So there is a `<svg>` element that is the child of the `<div>` and that is part of the same DOM? Is that operation synchronuous?

Comment: I have edited my post. I can display the svg and add a title. Except that only one title is added on my red circle whereas it should add it for each element of the "cls-1" class (class generated automatically when I created my svg in Photoshop).

Comment: Ccprog, I think it's because it's an operation asynchronus and i call the function in for loop. HAve you an idea to call this function for each element please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the clasical "callback in a loop" problem. At the time you call `getElementById(idSVG)` in your `.getTitle()` success handler, the `idSVG` has already changed. There are a lot of of ways to resolve this. Here's what I would do (If you don't know the destructuring pattern, [read up on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)):

```
function getTitle(id){
   // Déclaration des constantes et des variables
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuilleBDD = classeur.getSheetByName("BDD");

   // I can't see the need for your filter function. The .find()
   // in the next step takes care of that.
   const tDonnees = feuilleBDD.getRange("D2:E").getValues();
   // test the first value in the row, and return the complete row
   return tDonnees.find(([col1]) => col1 === id);
}
```

```
function addTitlesJS(){
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cls-1");
   for (let {id: idSVG} of elements){
     console.log(idSVG)
     // the handler gets the complete row as parameter
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([id, text]) => {
       // identify the element by the id value of the row
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<title>" + text + "</title>"
     }).getTitle(idSVG);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help ccprog. I learn so much with your help